# View pdf in mobile browser without downloading

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, mobile-browser, androidpdfviewer

I have a pdf link. I want to view pdf in mobile browser. So I use many way like object, embeded, frame, but each time pdf will be downloaded in my mobile application. Without downloading I want to view pdf in mobile browser. I also search about google doc, it provide view pdf via send link but some time it give error messages like "NO Preview Available". I simply use html and javascript. Can anybody solve this problem? Please help me. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "pdf will be downloaded in my mobile application" << you mean is it downloading to the device(Storage; can be viewed through file manager)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735968/open-pdf-in-new-browser-full-window

Comment: @hcheung Thanks for suggestion , but My problem pdf not viewing in mobile browser. it is working fine on desktop.

Comment: @user7328702 Yes whenever I call this url it is downloading to my device and I can viewed through file manager.  I don't want to download it.I have to show pdf in mobile browser.

Comment: Have you tried opening a link which ends with '.pdf` in the mobile browser? Eg. `www.something.lk/document.pdf`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed PDF in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382249/embed-pdf-in-mobile-browsers)